# If href is a certain url then replace

Tags: jquery

Looking to find a way to remove a part of the url and then put it all back together.

For example if site is https://example.com/ko/xxx/xxxx

I want to remove the 'ko' and it be https://example.com/xxx/xxxx

I also think I need to loop through the items as it's checking if the link has the classname `int-tooltip'

```js
var ko_link_url = $(".int-tooltip");
var ko_link_url_href = ko_link_url.attr("href");
var split = ko_link_url_href.split("/");
ko_link_url_href = ko_link_url_href.split("/");
ko_link_url_href = ko_link_url_href[3];

if (ko_link_url_href == "ko") {
  ko_link_url_href.replace(split[3], "");
}
```

Comment: Split it into an Array, Pop the part you want to remove, and Join it back.

Comment: var url = "https://example.com/ko/xxx/xxx";
url = url.split("/ko").join("");  You could do something like this

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this a bit more complicated than it needs to be - just search for `https://example.com/ko/` and replace with `https://example.com/`. Loop through elements with `.each`.

```
$('.int-tooltip').each(function() {
  this.href = this.href.replace('https://example.com/ko/', 'https://example.com/');
});
```

Comment: Does this work to add the url after the /ko/ as well?

Comment: `.replace` will only change the parts matched, and will leave the rest of the string alone - so everything after `https://example.com/ko/` will be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find all the anchors with class `int-tooltip` and `href` starting with `https://example.com/ko/` and remove the `ko` part.

```js
$("a[href^='https://example.com/ko/'].int-tooltip").attr("href", (_, href) =>
  href.replace("https://example.com/ko/", "https://example.com/")
);
```

```js
$("a[href^='https://example.com/ko/'].int-tooltip").attr("href", (_, href) =>
  href.replace("https://example.com/ko/", "https://example.com/")
);

$("pre").text($("p").html());
```

```css
p { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<p>
<a href="https://example.com/ko/xxx/xxxx">No class on this one</a>
<a href="https://example.com/ko/xxx/xxxx" class="int-tooltip">Change this one</a>
<a href="https://example.com/ok/xxx/xxxx" class="int-tooltip">No "ko"</a>
</p>

<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {

  var ko_link_url_href = "https://example.com/ko/xxx/xxxx";
  var urlParts = ko_link_url_href.split("/");
  $.each(urlParts, function(i, el) {
    if (el == "ko") {
      urlParts.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  var link_url_href = urlParts.join("/");
  console.log(link_url_href);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This splits the URL into an array, based on the `/` character. You can then iterate each part of the array and check the value. If it is found, you can use `.splice()` to remove it from the array. You can join the parts back with `/` character.